# Triming, xfade and concat videos from timeline with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, trim, timeline

I'm trying to build a command to output a video with some data provided with a json, sort of timeline.
In my example, I have 3 videos:
video1.mp4 (43s), video2.mp4 (28s), video3.mp4 (16s)

I'm trying to trim and set the same configuration to all videos, and I want to add transitions with (2s), "wiperight" from video1 to video2, and "wipeup" from video2 to video3.

And then concatenate all into one video.

I started with simple set configs + trim + concatenate:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 \
     -i video2.mp4 \
     -i video3.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v0]; \
    [1:v]trim=start=0:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v1]; \
    [2:v]trim=start=0:end=7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v2]; \
    [0:a]atrim=start=0:end=7,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
    [1:a]atrim=start=0:end=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
    [2:a]atrim=start=0:end=7,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
    [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

But now I can't seem to add the transitions:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 \
     -i video2.mp4 \
     -i video3.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v0]; \
    [1:v]trim=start=0:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v1]; \
    [2:v]trim=start=0:end=7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v2]; \
    [0:a]atrim=start=0:end=7,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
    [1:a]atrim=start=0:end=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
    [2:a]atrim=start=0:end=7,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
    [v0]xfade=transition=wiperight:duration=2:offset=5[fade0]; \
    [v1]xfade=transition=wipeup:duration=2:offset=8[fade1]; \
    [fade0][a0][fade1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart concatenado_transicoes.mp4
```

Error on terminal: "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_xfade_24"

I tried more different variations, the best I got was to actually build the file transitions.mp4, I can open and I can ear sound, but no image.

Thank you for your help,

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xfade, acrossfade, -to instead trim, atrim

```
ffmpeg \
-to  7 -i 'input0.mp4' \
-to 10 -i 'input1.mp4' \
-to  7 -i 'input2.mp4' \
-filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v0];
[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v1];
[2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=24[v2];
[v0][v1]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=2:offset=5[x1];
[x1][v2]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=2:offset=13;
[0:a]aresample=async=1[a0];
[1:a]aresample=async=1[a1];
[2:a]aresample=async=1[a2];
[a0][a1]acrossfade=d=2[c1];
[c1][a2]acrossfade=d=2
" out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you!
You dropped this 
If you can help one more time, what if i need to trim the video in the middle, for example, video1.mp4 (43s) i want to use trim to be between second 10 and 20?
Again thank you for the help.

Comment: just `... -ss 10 -to 20 -i video1.mp4 ...`